# Amazon (500310) Invalid operation: 1023;

Tags: database, pentaho, amazon-redshift, kettle, pentaho-spoon

While inserting data into redshift through pentaho ETL, I am facing the below error:

```
2016-03-15 08:00:17,444 ERROR [org.pentaho.di] 2016/03/15 08:00:17 - 

Redshift - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) :
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:

Redshift - Error inserting/updating row <br>
Redshift - [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 1023;
```

Answer (score 2):

Error `1023` occurs in redshift, when you have multiple writes/updates happening on the same database tables. You can read more about [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_TR_CONFLICT.html).